# ts-jest cannot find type information when using monorepo style tests directory in a typescript node project

Tags: node.js, typescript, testing, jestjs, ts-jest

I have separated jest's testing types and project's types by using the `references` and `composite` settings. But ts-jest is not able to find the type information in test files and throws multiple errors like: `error TS2304: Cannot find name 'expect'`.

This is the directory structure:

```sh
.
├── package.json
├── src
│   └── index.ts
├── tests
│   ├── index.test.ts
│   └── tsconfig.json
├── tsconfig.json
```

`tsconfig.json`:

```json
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "composite": true,
  },
  "include": ["src"]
}
```

`tests/tsconfig.json`:

```json
{
  "extends": "../tsconfig.json",
  "references": [
    {
      "name": "my-lib",
      "path": ".."
    }
  ],
  "compilerOptions": {
    "types": ["jest"],
    "rootDir": "..",
    "noEmit": true
  },
  "include": ["."]
}
```

`package.json`:

```json
{
  "jest": {
    "preset": "ts-jest",
    "environment": "node"
  }
}
```

how to integrate ts-jest in such a projects?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update jest configuration to define exactly tsconfig file for `ts-jest`:

`package.json`

```
{
  "jest": {
    "preset": "ts-jest",
    "environment": "node",
    "globals": {
      "ts-jest": {
        "tsconfig": "./tests/tsconfig.json"
      }
    }
  }
}
```